# Sails rejecting PostgreSQL connection with sails-postgresql module

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, connection-pooling, sails-postgresql

I have a sails web app in an intranet environment. An average of ~12 users are logged in at the same time. Eventually I get the classic connection refused message from `sails-postgresql` that lasts for at least 3 minutes, denying all http requests made to the app.

```
Error creating a connection to Postgresql using the following settings:
{ 
...
schema: true,
ssl: false,
adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
poolSize: 50
...
}
```

I either get `{ [Error: write ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'write' }` or `{ [Error: write ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }`.

My PostgreSQL logs the following message:
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

As you can see, my `poolSize` in `sails.config.connections` is set to 50 and my `max_connections` in `postgresql.conf` is set to 100. I'm not using this database for something else.

**Is my poolsize set ok? Is it a problem from Sails or is it Postgres'?**

Comment: I'm guessing, it is leaking connections somewhere, which gets automatically rectified by parameter [poolIdleTimeout](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/lib/defaults.js#L31), but doesn't help in the long run. Probably worthwhile logging it against Sails. I wouldn't blame the `node-postgres` driver for that, it is rock-solid when it comes to connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing *max_connections* in postgres config file *postgresql.conf*, in my Ubuntu 15.04 linux it is located in this path:

> /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf

Comment: I have it as max_connections = 100. How much more should I increase it? Poolsize in Sails connections is 50.